# React Function is not returning component after being called from onchange method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am calling 'reload' function when the value is changed on react-select component. The control is going into the function but it is not returning the component from that function. I have tried calling the component from render then the component is being called.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import removeDuplicates from '../../helpers.js';
import Dashboard from '../../containers/Dashboard';

class ExportDropDown extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { dropdown: null }
        this.reload = this.reload.bind(this);
    }

    reload(value) {
        console.log('val', value);
        const filter = (
            <div className={'lll'}>
                <Dashboard filter={'abc'} />
            </div>
        );
        return filter;
    }

    render() {
        const uniqueArray = removeDuplicates(this.props.data, 'Expert');
        return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.reload}>
                    {uniqueArray.map((d) => <option key={d.Expert} value={d.Expert}>{d.Expert}</option>)}
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ExportDropDown;
```

Comment: Can you show the full code where the behavior you've described happens?

Comment: I have added the full code already, i am calling the function here onChange={this.reload}, and returning the component from that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few fixes on your code. Please take a look to understand how:

1 - We control the select input value by keeping it's value in our state. (**onSelectValueChange**)

2 - How our conditional dashboard component renders with the current select input value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import removeDuplicates from '../../helpers.js'
import Dashboard from '../../containers/Dashboard'

class ExportDropDown extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = { 
        dropdownValue: null
      }
      this.onSelectValueChange = this.onSelectValueChange.bind(this)
    }

    onSelectValueChange (event) {
      this.setState({
        dropdownValue: event.target.value
      })
    }

    render() {
      const uniqueArray = removeDuplicates(this.props.data, 'Expert')
      return (
        <div>
          <select 
            onChange={this.onSelectValueChange}
            value={dropdownValue}
          >
            {
              uniqueArray.map(
                (d) => <option key={d.Expert} value={d.Expert}>{d.Expert}</option>
              )
            }
          </select>
          {
            dropdownValue &&
            <div className={'lll'}>
              <Dashboard filter={dropdownValue} />
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      )
    }

}

export default ExportDropDown
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to return a value to the `onChange` callback which doesn't expect a return value. Only the return value of your `render` hook will be rendered.

You could keep the dropdown value in your state and decide in your `render` hook what to render:

```
render() {
    const filterElem = this.createFilter();

    ...
    return (
       <div>
            Something
            ...
            { filterElem }
       </div>
    );
}

reload(event) {
    const { value: dropDownValue } = event.target;
    this.setState({ dropDownValue });
}

createFilter() {
    const { dropDownValue } = this.state;
    return dropDownValue ? <MyFilterComponent /> : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in select tags:

```
onChange= { (e) => { this.reload(e.target.value) } }
```